# Retrieve some text from sql

Tags: c#, sql

I created a news website and this one function has to display data from SQL with LINQ. I want to display just like preview news in home page and then if user want to read more about it just click the link "Read more.." . In this case I do not know how to retrieve data from "NewsDesc" colomn in SQL table but just first 25 or 30 character. This is my html code  :

```
<td>
    <img src="Images/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NewsID")%>.jpg" alt="" />
</td>
<td>
    <strong>
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NewsTitle")%>
        <br />
    </strong>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NewsDesc")%>
    <br />
</td>
<td>
    <a href="News.aspx?id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NewsID")%>">Read More..</a>
</td>
```

Must I code something in code behind too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In News.Aspx, you'll need to call `Request.Querystring("id")` and use that to retrieve the rest of the news item.

Querystrings can be modified by the user, and you have no control over this. You should verify the input is what you expect.

Comment: Thankyou for answering @Tim . So i can not modify the displaying SQL data (like retrieve just first 10 letter or something like that), right ?

Comment: It's tough to say - if you post some of the code from the codebehind file, it'll be easier to help you.